# Unit test inject dependency like controller for service in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

Lets see, we have this according to:https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });
  });
});
```

now i am making service and factory, is there any equivalent to ____$controller____ for service and factory? so i can inject it with something else like:

```
var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
```

and change the inner functions of the dependency so i can test it, or is there any better approach?

**Edit:** to make question more clear
here is the example of the question:

i have this:

```
var app = angular.module("app").service("MyService",["$scope","$http",function($scope,$http){
    this.myFunction = function(){
        $http.get("/myApi/1");
    }
}]);
```

how do i use the equivalent of

```
var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
```

so i can inject $scope and $http with something else to myService?

Comment: Did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40234868/2545680) help?

Comment: no, i am asking about the equivalent of _$controller_ for service and factory so i can inject the dependency, not asking how to inject the dependency in controller,

Comment: _so i can inject the dependency_ - inject where?

Comment: controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: my_own_pseudo_dependency });

Comment: I showed you that in my answer, search for `controllerDependency: controllerDependency `.

Comment: you showing for controller, can you do for service and factory? i know controller can, but can it be done for service and factory? i searched for long about this but can't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126605/discussion-between-maximus-and-hans-yulian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject dependencies to factories or services on the go, but you can `mock` the dependencies with your custom objects and have angular substitute them automatically. You can use `$provide` for that. Here is an example:

```
angular.module('app').service('some', function(dependencyService) {

});
```

When testing:

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
   $provide.value('dependencyService', {

   });
}));
```

Comment: unfortunately, the $provide.value is not a function, i noticed that yours quite similar to https://www.sitepoint.com/unit-testing-angularjs-services-controllers-providers/, but if i follow sitepoint, i got the error where you can't initialize module after injector initialized

Comment: @HansYulian, so how is your progress?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i already go back from office yesterday. here is the code:
(function () {
 describe("Testing service", function () {
  beforeEach(function ($provide) {
   $provide.value("$http", function () {
    this.get = function (target, header) {
     return "ok";
    }
   });
  });
  var APIServiceObject;
  beforeEach(inject(function (APIService) {
   APIServiceObject = APIService;
  }));
  it("test", function () {
   expect(APIServiceObject.getHeader()).toEqual({});
  });
 });
})();

Comment: @HansYulian, updated, `module` call was missing. Please see if it's working now.

Comment: Oh i finally got the answer but from somewhere else, i will put it here

Comment: yeah, sure, let's see how it's different from mine

Comment: done, there is a bit difference, first is the  module('timesheet'); inside the first beforeEach, and then the inject onthe second beforeEach

Comment: well, I don't see how it's different regarding to the _question_ you asked, since you just post additional details irrelevant to the _question_ :). anyways, `module` function in your code can accept multiple params, so I edited a bit your code

Comment: well anyway thank you for the help ;) at least my problem now solved

Comment: @HansYulian, no problem. You can accept my answer or yours)

Answer (score 1):

After doing a workarround, i found out from https://www.sitepoint.com/unit-testing-angularjs-services-controllers-providers/ about the service. i tested out the tutorial here and here is the test script:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('services', [])
        .service('sampleSvc', ['$window', 'modalSvc', function ($window, modalSvc) {
            this.showDialog = function (message, title) {
                if (title) {
                    modalSvc.showModalDialog({
                        title: title,
                        message: message
                    });
                } else {
                    $window.alert(message);
                }
            };
      }]);
    describe("Testing service", function () {
        var mockWindow, mockModalSvc, sampleSvcObj;
        beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
                $provide.service('$window', function () {
                    this.alert = jasmine.createSpy('alert');
                });
                $provide.service('modalSvc', function () {
                    this.showModalDialog = jasmine.createSpy('showModalDialog');
                });
            }, 'services'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($window, modalSvc, sampleSvc) {
            mockWindow = $window;
            mockModalSvc = modalSvc;
            sampleSvcObj = sampleSvc;
        }));
        it('should show alert when title is not passed into showDialog', function () {
            var message = "Some message";
            sampleSvcObj.showDialog(message);

            expect(mockWindow.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith(message);
            expect(mockModalSvc.showModalDialog).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should show modal when title is passed into showDialog', function () {
            var message = "Some message";
            var title = "Some title";
            sampleSvcObj.showDialog(message, title);

            expect(mockModalSvc.showModalDialog).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                message: message,
                title: title
            });
            expect(mockWindow.alert).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
})();
```

and i try my own test script:

```
(function () {
    describe("Testing service", function () {
        var mockHttp, mockCookies, mockApi;
        beforeEach(function () {
            module(function ($provide) {
                $provide.service('$http', function () {
                    this.defaults = {
                        headers: {
                            common: {

                            }
                        }
                    };
                });
                $provide.service('$cookies', function () {

                });
            });
            module('timesheet');
        });

        beforeEach(inject(function ($http, $cookies, APIService) {
            mockHttp = $http;
            mockCookies = $cookies;
            mockApi = APIService;
        }));
        it('Test Service', function () {

        });
    });
})();
```

apparently in somewhere in my code, there is an app.run which inside do the

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookies.get('sessionToken');
```

and causes the error the moment i inject the $http with something else because headers not defined, i thought it was from my own test script because they are using same name, but apparently this is the one causing problem.

So, actually the moment we load in testing mode, the angularjs still do the whole running of application, in which i forgot about this one.